# Convert Collection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, collections, dictionary

How can I convert a Collection from One type to another in Ruby.

I have a collection MileageRecords(Date, Odometer, Gallons) and would like to generate a list of FooObject(Miles, MPG). The FooObject properties are calculated from the Mileage record.

This gets me the data, but I don't see how to create a collection

```
LogEntry.all.each_with_index do |log, index|
  if index > 0
    miles = LogEntry.all[index - 1].odometer - log.odometer
    mpg = miles / log.gallons
    puts "#{log.date} #{miles} #{mpg}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
fuel_economy = LogEntry.all.each_cons(2).map do |prev, curr|
   miles = curr.odometer - prev.odometer
   mpg = miles / curr.gallons
   FuelEconomy.new(miles, mpg)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on what to call the FooObject? :)

Comment: How about FuelEconomy or MileageEfficiency :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do any sort of implicit type casting, especially with your own classes. The best method is probably to create a `to_foo_object` method for MileageRecords

```
class MileageRecords
  def to_foo_object
    FooObject.new(miles, mpg) # you'll need to define these variables somehow
  end
end
```

Then you can call

```
mileage_records.map{|mr| mr.to_foo_object }
```

or to shorten it up a bit

```
mileage_records.map(&:to_foo_object)
```